# Getting MailItem in MailItem.Send - Event Handler

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-interop

In my code, I'm generating an Email, which is then shown to the user so they can edit it before sending. After they're done with editing, I want to store the edited Email as a File, but I don't know how to access it after it has been sent. The most logical way to go about it seems to be to react to the Send - Event to store it as soon as the user sends it:

```
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
'Fill oMail
oMail.Display()
AddHandler oMail.Send, AddressOf MailSent
```

However, the signature for MailSent has to look like this:

```
Private Sub MailSent(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
```

I don't know how I would access the MailItem in MailSent since there's no sender object or anything of the like.

Maybe this isn't supposed to be possible and i'm supposed to read the last item in the Folder "Sent" Instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `MailItem` object into your own class with a constructor that takes `MailItem` as a parameter, saves it in a member variable, and sets the event handler. When the event handler fires, you have your class variable to reference.

You can also use `Application.ItemSend` event, which does pass the item being sent (could be `MailItem` or `MeetingRequest` object) as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Using Application.ItemSend instead worked to get the mail after it's sent. I ended up using both of your suggestions though since I needed some additional parameters!